# How to initiate different and multiple threads with clicking a button in tkinter python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, urllib, python-multithreading

I am new to python and I am developing this simple downloader app that gets a URL form the user and downloads it to the place they specify. I want the download button to create a thread each time the user hits the button so that each thread would be responsible for one download so the user can download multiple items at a time. As a result, the program wouldn't freeze with each download but I have no idea how to do such thing. I have tried many ways but none of them seem to be working. I could really use some help.
Here is my code without threads:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont
import random
import urllib.request
import requests
import wget


def printsth():
    print("Yay it works! ")


def main_menu():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('8-bit downloader ')
    root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\rayanravesh\PycharmProjects\GUI_Calculator\icon.ico")
    root.geometry("600x300")
    # the top menu
    num = IntVar()
    chum = IntVar()
    var = IntVar()
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    submenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=submenu)

    def custom_op():
        custom = Toplevel()
        custom.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\rayanravesh\PycharmProjects\GUI_Calculator\icon.ico")
    submenu.add_command(label="Customization ", command=custom_op)

    def settings_op():
        global gps
        set_win = Toplevel()
        set_win.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\rayanravesh\PycharmProjects\GUI_Calculator\icon.ico")
        path_label = Label(set_win, text="Current default download path: ")
        path_entry = Entry(set_win, width=30)
        file_read = open('Data.txt', 'r')
        data_base = file_read.read()
        path_entry.insert(0, data_base)
        file_read.close()

        def default_output():
            global location
            file_read2 = open('Data.txt', 'r+')
            file_read2.truncate(0)
            file_read2.close()
            write_file2 = open('Data.txt', 'w')
            write_file2.write(path_entry.get())
            write_file2.close()
            location = path_entry.get() + "\\"
            default_location = location.replace("\\", "\\\\")
        path_btn = Button(set_win, text="Submit ", command=default_output)
        path_label.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
        path_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
        path_btn.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    submenu.add_command(label="Settings ", command=settings_op)
    submenu.add_separator()
    submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

    # the section menu
    editmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Sections(soon)", menu=editmenu)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Downloader", command=printsth)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Converter", command=printsth)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Media Player", command=printsth)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Editor", command=printsth)
    # the tool bar
    toolbar = Frame(root, bg="light gray")
    insert_button = Button(toolbar, text="Insert an image", command=printsth)
    insert_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
    print_button = Button(toolbar, text="Print", command=printsth)
    print_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    # the download function
    def download_image():
        global formatname
        if num.get() == 1:
            name = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
        else:
            name = str(name_entry.get())
        formatname = str(format_entry.get())
        if var.get() == 1:
            operator = str(url_entry.get())
            formatname = '.' + operator[-3] + operator[-2] + operator[-1]
        else:
            pass
        fullname = str(name) + formatname
        url = str(url_entry.get())
        fw = open('file-size.txt', 'w')
        file_size = int(requests.head(url, headers={'accept-encoding': ''}).headers['Content-Length'])
        fw.write(str(file_size))
        fw.close()
        path = str(output_entry.get()) + "\\"
        if chum.get() == 1:
            filee = open('Data.txt', 'r')
            destination = filee.read()
            path = destination + "\\"
            output_entry.insert(0, destination)
            filee.close()
        else:
            output_entry.delete(0, END)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.replace("\\", "\\\\") + fullname)

    # the status bar
    status_bar = Label(root, text="Downloading...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    # the download frame
    body_frame = Frame(root, bg="light blue")
    download_button = Button(body_frame, text="Download! ", command=download_image, border=3, width=20, height=5)
    download_design = tkFont.Font(size=12, slant='italic')
    download_button['font'] = download_design
    download_button.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=5)
    body_frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    # the main interaction menu
    inter_frame = Frame(root)
    url_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    label = Label(inter_frame, text="Enter the image URL: ")
    file_format = Label(inter_frame, text="Choose your file format: ")
    format_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    file_name = Label(inter_frame, text="File's name: ")
    name_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    check_name = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Give a random name", variable=num)
    check_format = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Download with default format", variable=var)
    check_default = Checkbutton(inter_frame, text="Download to default path", variable=chum)
    check_default.deselect()
    output_path = Label(inter_frame, text="Choose output path: ")
    output_entry = Entry(inter_frame, width=30)
    file_name.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    name_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    check_name.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    label.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    url_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    file_format.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    format_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    format_entry.insert(0, '.')
    check_format.pack(anchor=CENTER)
    output_path.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    output_entry.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    check_default.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
    inter_frame.pack(expand=1)
    root.mainloop()

    # the end!


main_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that I used for something similar in combination with Tk:

```
import threading

def join_thread(thread):
    thread.join(0)
    if thread.is_alive():
        # the thread has not finished yet -> handle it (e.g. check again after
        # a certain time)
        pass

def start_threaded(root, timeout):
    thread = threading.Thread(
            target= ...,    # put your downloading function here
            args=...        # put your arguments here, e.g.: (URL, targetPath)
        )
    thread.start()
    root.after(timeout, join_thread, thread)
```

Bind `start_threaded` to the according button and pass the following parameters: the `root` of your Tk application (we need it for checking if the thread has finished with `root.after`) and a `timeout` value in milliseconds after which we will check if the download has finished.

Note that I am not sure if Tk is thread-safe. So I would not access any widgets directly from the download threads but pass every information that is needed as an argument when creating the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample @Stefan Scheller! Though I don't understand the code well. And when I run the code I get an instant error. Could you please explain the steps one more time and if possible simpler? I don't what I have done wrong. It would mean a lot to me.

Comment: @OmidKetabollahi The code I posted above is a template you can use in your project but you have to complete it by providing the function and the arguments to the construction of the thread. Can you tell specifically where you have problems to understand the code?

Comment: Schellar, I just don't generally understand the code specially the first function. What is the first function responsible for and should I change it?

Comment: @OmidKetabollahi The first function is used to check if the thread has finished and to free its resources by joining it. Joining in that sense means merging the program flow back together. You should adapt the function if you want to add some action in case the thread hasn't finished. This could happen if the connection for the download is slow or gets interrupted. I suggest to read an introduction for Python threading [like this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).